# Read a binary file full of integers and print it out in an ASCII format in C

Tags: c

I am trying to take in a file that is full of 4-byte binary integers. I am trying to use `read()` after I open this file but cannot figure out this function at all. I can't figure out how to format my code and I can find almost no code examples for this specific type of thing I am trying to do. I want to read a binary file full of integers, and then print each integer in an ASCII format. I also want to be able to do this without knowing the exact number of binary int's there are before writing my code. Some fragment I have been modifying/trying is something like this, but I can't figure out how to implement something like this into a loop either.

```
char *infile = argv[1];
int fd = open(infile, O_RDONLY);

   int value;
   int rc = read(fd, &value, sizeof(int));
   printf("%d", value);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A call to `read` will give you back the number of bytes read so you can simply keep going until you get something other than the requested size, something like:

```
ssize_t rc = read (fd, &value, sizeof value);
while (rc == sizeof value) {
    printf ("%d\n", value);
    rc = read (fd, &value, sizeof value);
}
if (rc == 0) {
    printf ("End of file reached okay\n");
} else if (rc < 0) {
    printf ("Some sort of error, errno = %d\n", errno);
} else {
    printf ("Only %d/%d bytes read\n", rc, sizeof value);
}
```

As you can see, the final value received from `read` decides what happened. `-1` indicates an error of some sort, `0` indicates end of file was reached and any other value (other than four of course) means a partial read, possibly because the file wasn't created properly.

You may also want to reconsider the use of the low-level I/O functions like `open` and `read` unless you have a very specific need, they're not actually part of the ISO C standard, and you can achieve the same ends with the `fopen` and `fread` stream-based functions.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the return value of the open, as well as looping until the read doesn't return data anymore. This can be because the file is ended, or because of an error.

```
int rc, value;
while ((rc =  = read (fd, &value, sizeof(int)) != sizeof(int))
    printf ("%d\n", value);

if(rc == 0)
{
   // ok
}
else if(rc < 0)
{
   // error in errno.
   perror ("Read returned the following error:");   // perror will print an appropriate error message from errno.
}
else
{
    // file contains data which doesn't match up to a multiple of sizeof(int), so value may be undetermined here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `read`  function returns how many bytes were actualy read, -1 if an error happen or 0 if the end of file was reached, so you can use that to read all ints even if you don't know how many are there.

So using read, your code could be like this:

```
char *infile = argv[1];
int fd = open(infile, O_RDONLY);

int value;
int rc;
while ((rc = read(fd, &value, sizeof(int)) > 0) {
    printf("%d\n", value);
}
```

Using fopen/fread (which is recommended):

```
char *infile = argv[1];
FILE *fp = fopen(infile, "r");

int value;
int rc;
while ((rc = fread(&value, sizeof(int), 1, fp) > 0) {
    printf("%d\n", value);
}
```

Note that `fread` is a little different from `read`, the second argument is the size of each value, and the third argument how many values you want to read. It will return how many values (not bytes) it actualy read (in this case will be 1 when there are values to read).

Another thing worth mention, you said you want to read 4 bytes values. Int is 4 bytes in most modern platforms, but there is no garantee of that, if you want to make sure it will always be 4 bytes, include the header `<stdint.h>` and use `int32_t`.